# flat nested json inside arrays with Python

Tags: python, json

I want to convert this:

```
{} Json
  {} 0
    [] variants
      {} 0
         fileName
         id
         {} mediaType
            baseFilePtah
            id
            name
         sortOrder
      {} 1
         fileName
         id
         {} mediaType
            baseFilePtah
            id
            name
         sortOrder
```

Into this:

```
{} Json
  {} 0
   [] variants
     {} 0
         fileName
         id
         mediaType_baseFilePath
         mediaType_id
         mediaType_name
         SortOrder
     {} 1
         fileName
         id
         mediaType_baseFilePath
         mediaType_id
         mediaType_name
         SortOrder
```

Basically each

```
 {}
   {}
```

should be merged together. But not rows numbers.

This is the code I wrote:

```
def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}
    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            print type(x), name
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            print type(x), name
            out[name[:-1]] = x
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x
    flatten(y)
    return out

def generatejson(response2):
    # response 2 is [(first data set), (second data set)]  convert it to dictionary {0: (first data set), 1: (second data set)}
    sample_object = {i: data for i, data in enumerate(response2)}
    # begin to flat (merge sub-jsons)
    flat = {k: flatten_json(v) for k, v in sample_object.items()}
    return json.dumps(flat, sort_keys=True)
```

This is the result of the code on my sample data:
[image]

As you can see `manufacturer` was merged but `mediaType` was not.
The code prints:

```
<type 'dict'> 
<type 'list'> additionalLocaleInfos_
<type 'list'> variants_
<type 'dict'> manufacturer_
```

My aim was that `type list` will be further investigated in the recursion. The code suppose to detect that inside the `variants list` there is also a `dict` of `mediaType` but it doesn't.

Data sample for `generatejson(response2)`  - is a `list` of this structure:

```
[{"additionalLocaleInfos": [], "approved": false, "approvedBy": null, "approvedOn": null, "catalogId": 4, "code": "611", 
"createdOn": "2018-03-24 09:39", "customsCode": null, "deletedOn": null, "id": 1, "invariantName": "Leisure Ali Baba Trousers", "isPermanent": false, "locale": null, "madeIn": null, 
"manufacturer": {"createdOn": "2018-02-23 18:20", "deletedOn": null, "id": 1, "invariantName": "Unknown", "updatedOn": "2018-02-23 18:20"},
 "onNoStockShowComingSoon": false, "season": "", "updatedOn": "2018-03-24 09:39",
 "variants": [{"assets": [{"fileName": "mu/2016/05/16/leisure-ali-baba-trousers-32956-0.jpg", "id": 1, 
 "mediaType": {"baseFilePath": "Catalog", "id": 7, "name": "Product Main Image"}, "sortOrder": 0}]} ]}]
```

Full example can be found here (but not mandatory for the question)
http://www.filedropper.com/file_389

How can I make it look inside the list to check if it's made of more objects?

This code works only without arrays. For some reason It doesn't look inside the array to see what objects are in it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't like images where text is possible, especially of data and code, as we can't experiment on images, or grasp their meaning as fast as we can with text. We also don't like external links where copy-paste is possible, because links can age and die (like your link did). Please note that wherever possible post JSON or another computer-readable representation of your data, or code that generates it (like Python's dict literal) inside the question itself. You can post additional data on an external site, but the question should be clear without it.

Comment: @Amadan The images are just for clrefication they are not actualy needed. Sadly I can not upload to stackoverflow text file. The data sample is too long to paste in the question. See updated link.

Comment: Make a sample input data that illustrates your problem when passed through your code. You don't need 10Gb data to show your point, a 20-line pared-down JSON should be enough. Also show what your desired output JSON would be. This will give you many more willing answerers.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? For instance, in your data (as downloaded) there are multiple disparate objects within the `attributes` list; merging those into one dict makes no sense and loses data.

Comment: @AKX I want to load the data sample to relational table. Having nested Jsons means having sub table which I don't want... empty arrays are ok. each array will be a table. sometimes not all fields have values.

Comment: Fair enough. Let's see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will flatten a dict structure containing dicts, lists and tuples into a flat dict.

The `json_data` blob is an excerpt from the data you posted.

```
import json
import collections

json_data = """
{"additionalLocaleInfos":[],"approved":false,"approvedBy":null,"approvedOn":null,"catalogId":4,"code":"611","createdOn":"2018-03-24 09:39","customsCode":null,"deletedOn":null,"id":1,"invariantName":"Leisure Ali Baba Trousers","isPermanent":false,"locale":null,"madeIn":null,"manufacturer":{"createdOn":"2018-02-23 18:20","deletedOn":null,"id":1,"invariantName":"Unknown","updatedOn":"2018-02-23 18:20"},"onNoStockShowComingSoon":false,"season":"","updatedOn":"2018-03-24 09:39","variants":[{"assets":[{"fileName":"mu/2016/05/16/leisure-ali-baba-trousers-32956-0.jpg","id":1,"mediaType":{"baseFilePath":"Catalog","id":7,"name":"Product Main Image"},"sortOrder":0},{"fileName":"080113/3638.jpg","id":2,"mediaType":{"baseFilePath":"Catalog","id":8,"name":"Product Additional Image"},"sortOrder":0},{"fileName":"mu/2016/05/16/leisure-ali-baba-trousers-32956-1.jpg","id":3,"mediaType":{"baseFilePath":"Catalog","id":8,"name":"Product Additional Image"},"sortOrder":0},{"fileName":"mu/2015/07/21/leisure-ali-baba-trousers-13730-0.jpg","id":4,"mediaType":{"baseFilePath":"Catalog","id":8,"name":"Product Additional Image"},"sortOrder":0},{"fileName":"mu/2016/05/16/leisure-ali-baba-trousers-32956-2.jpg","id":5,"mediaType":{"baseFilePath":"Catalog","id":8,"name":"Product Additional Image"},"sortOrder":0},{"fileName":"mu/2015/07/29/leisure-ali-baba-trousers-13853-0.jpg","id":6,"mediaType":{"baseFilePath":"Catalog","id":8,"name":"Product Additional Image"},"sortOrder":0}],"attributes":[{"attribute":{"code":"COL","cultureNeutralName":"Color","id":1,"useAsFilter":false},"code":"BLACK","groupId":0,"id":3,"invariantValue":"BLACK","locale":null,"sortOrder":0,"valueLocale":null},{"attribute":{"code":"SZ","cultureNeutralName":"Size","id":2,"useAsFilter":false},"code":"ONE SIZE","groupId":0,"id":7,"invariantValue":"ONE SIZE","locale":null,"sortOrder":0,"valueLocale":null},{"attribute":{"code":"WEIGHT","cultureNeutralName":"WEIGHT","id":14,"useAsFilter":false},"code":"0.30","groupId":0,"id":2,"invariantValue":"0.30","locale":null,"sortOrder":0,"valueLocale":null},{"attribute":{"code":"STLPTND","cultureNeutralName":"OsStyleOptionId","id":25,"useAsFilter":false},"code":"2","groupId":0,"id":6,"invariantValue":"2","locale":null,"sortOrder":0,"valueLocale":null},{"attribute":{"code":"STLNMBR","cultureNeutralName":"OsStyleNumber","id":26,"useAsFilter":false},"code":"611-1412","groupId":0,"id":1,"invariantValue":"611-1412","locale":null,"sortOrder":0,"valueLocale":null},{"attribute":{"code":"SZFCTEN","cultureNeutralName":"SizeFacetEn","id":35,"useAsFilter":true},"code":"S","groupId":0,"id":8,"invariantValue":"S","locale":null,"sortOrder":0,"valueLocale":null},{"attribute":{"code":"SZFCTEN","cultureNeutralName":"SizeFacetEn","id":35,"useAsFilter":true},"code":"M","groupId":0,"id":9,"invariantValue":"M","locale":null,"sortOrder":0,"valueLocale":null},{"attribute":{"code":"SZFCTEN","cultureNeutralName":"SizeFacetEn","id":35,"useAsFilter":true},"code":"L","groupId":0,"id":10,"invariantValue":"L","locale":null,"sortOrder":0,"valueLocale":null}],"cost":0,"createdOn":"2018-03-24 09:39","deletedOn":null,"eaN1":"2500002822528","eaN2":null,"eaN3":null,"id":1,"isDefault":false,"locale":null,"sku":"611-1412-28","sortOrder":0,"upC1":null,"upC2":null,"upC3":null,"updatedOn":"2018-03-24 09:39","variantInventories":[{"defectiveQty":0,"id":1,"lastUpdate":"2018-03-24 09:39","orderLevelQty":0,"preorderQty":0,"qtyInStock":0,"reorderQty":0,"reservedQty":100,"transferredQty":0,"variantId":1,"warehouseId":1}],"variantPrices":[{"id":1,"price":5,"priceListId":1,"priceType":{"code":"Base price","id":1,"remarks":null},"validFrom":"2018-03-24 09:39","validUntil":"2068-03-24 09:39","variantId":1}]}]}
""".strip()

data = json.loads(json_data)

def flatten_object(d, out=None, name_path=()):
    out = (out or collections.OrderedDict())
    iterator = (d.items() if isinstance(d, dict) else enumerate(d))
    for index, value in iterator:
        i_path = name_path + (index,)
        if isinstance(value, (list, dict, tuple)):
            flatten_object(value, out, i_path)
        else:
            out[i_path] = value
    return out

for key, value in flatten_object(data).items():
    print('_'.join(str(atom) for atom in key), value)
```

The output here will be something like

```
approved False
approvedBy None
approvedOn None
[...]
variants_0_cost 0
variants_0_createdOn 2018-03-24 09:39
variants_0_deletedOn None
variants_0_eaN1 2500002822528
variants_0_eaN2 None
variants_0_eaN3 None
variants_0_assets_0_fileName mu/2016/05/16/leisure-ali-baba-trousers-32956-0.jpg
variants_0_assets_0_id 1
variants_0_assets_0_mediaType_baseFilePath Catalog
variants_0_assets_0_mediaType_id 7
variants_0_assets_0_mediaType_name Product Main Image
variants_0_assets_0_sortOrder 0
variants_0_assets_1_fileName 080113/3638.jpg
variants_0_assets_1_id 2
variants_0_assets_1_mediaType_baseFilePath Catalog
variants_0_assets_1_mediaType_id 8
variants_0_assets_1_mediaType_name Product Additional Image
variants_0_assets_1_sortOrder 0
variants_0_assets_2_fileName mu/2016/05/16/leisure-ali-baba-trousers-32956-1.jpg
[...]
variants_0_attributes_0_attribute_code COL
variants_0_attributes_0_attribute_cultureNeutralName Color
variants_0_attributes_0_attribute_id 1
variants_0_attributes_0_attribute_useAsFilter False
variants_0_attributes_0_code BLACK
variants_0_attributes_0_groupId 0
variants_0_attributes_0_id 3
variants_0_attributes_0_invariantValue BLACK
variants_0_attributes_0_locale None
variants_0_attributes_0_sortOrder 0
variants_0_attributes_0_valueLocale None
variants_0_attributes_1_attribute_code SZ
variants_0_attributes_1_attribute_cultureNeutralName Size
variants_0_attributes_1_attribute_id 2
variants_0_attributes_1_attribute_useAsFilter False
variants_0_attributes_1_code ONE SIZE
variants_0_attributes_1_groupId 0
variants_0_attributes_1_id 7
variants_0_attributes_1_invariantValue ONE SIZE
variants_0_attributes_1_locale None
variants_0_attributes_1_sortOrder 0
variants_0_attributes_1_valueLocale None
variants_0_attributes_2_attribute_code WEIGHT
variants_0_attributes_2_attribute_cultureNeutralName WEIGHT
variants_0_attributes_2_attribute_id 14
variants_0_attributes_2_attribute_useAsFilter False
variants_0_attributes_2_code 0.30
variants_0_attributes_2_groupId 0
[...]
```

but you'll probably only want to run this on a single object within `variants`, or a list of `attributes`.

```
variant = data['variants'][0]
merged_flattened_assets = dict()
for asset in variant['assets']:
    merged_flattened_assets.update({
        '_'.join(key): value
        for (key, value)
        in flatten_object(asset).items()
    })

for key, value in merged_flattened_assets.items():
    print(key, value)
```

outputs

```
fileName mu/2015/07/29/leisure-ali-baba-trousers-13853-0.jpg
id 6
mediaType_baseFilePath Catalog
mediaType_id 8
mediaType_name Product Additional Image
sortOrder 0
```

Comment: Thx but what your code does it flat everything.... see my example only sub-json of json should be merge into his parents. note that under {0} I merged `manufacurer_ ` I did not create `0_manufacturer_`   What I did with manufacturer is what I need for the others. You don't need to flat the array only look inside of it to check for sub-jsons

Comment: I think it would be easier to find out why my code skip arrays... My code already produce the desired result in my format.. I just need to make it look inside the arrays rather than skipping them.

Comment: I mentioned it flattens everything in the post, yes, and I also mentioned that you'll probably only want to run it on parts of the structure.

Comment: Still even if I run your code over part of my data it behaves differently.. I think when I encounter a list I need to convert it to something else and then continue my code but I'm not sure what